Difficult to understand behavior of the Promise's catch() in Javascript
Why is removing catch() from the Promise (p2) the result running as expected but keeping catch() the flow is different? However, the catch() in the Promise (p2) is not executed. Don't know what I'm misunderstanding...

removing catch() from the Promise (p2)



const onFinally_1 = () => {
    console.log('Promise settled! 1');
    i++;
};
const onFinally_3 = () => console.log('Promise settled! 3');

const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(1);
})
    .then(
        (res) => Promise.resolve(onFinally_1()).then(() => res),
        (err) => Promise.resolve(onFinally_1()).then(() => { throw err; })
    )
    .then((result) => console.log(result), (x) => { console.log('B'); throw x; })
    .catch((error) => console.log('=>', error))

const p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(3);
})
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    // .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    .then(
        (res) => Promise.resolve(onFinally_3()).then(() => res),
        (err) => Promise.resolve(onFinally_3()).then(() => { throw err; })
    )



Result:
Promise settled! 1
3
B
Promise settled! 3
ReferenceError: i is not defined...


keeping catch() from the Promise (p2)



const onFinally_1 = () => {
    console.log('Promise settled! 1');
    i++;
};
const onFinally_3 = () => console.log('Promise settled! 3');

const p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(1);
})
    .then(
        (res) => Promise.resolve(onFinally_1()).then(() => res),
        (err) => Promise.resolve(onFinally_1()).then(() => { throw err; })
    )
    .then((result) => console.log(result), (x) => { console.log('B'); throw x; })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))

const p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(3);
})
    .then((result) => console.log(result))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    .then(
        (res) => Promise.resolve(onFinally_3()).then(() => res),
        (err) => Promise.resolve(onFinally_3()).then(() => { throw err; })
    )



Result:
Promise settled! 1
3
B
ReferenceError: i is not defined...
Promise settled! 3


"the flow is different?" - no. You simply have two totally independent flows! Changing anything in either will not affect the other, but it will affect the overall ordering of their concurrent execution.

If you have time, please run these examples and see if the results are the same as what you think. Many thanks!

I didn't say I think that the results should be the same. Really you should not expect any particular result at all!

then and catch create NEW promises and thus NEW MICROTASKS, so basically here you have parallel chains of microtasks from p1 and p2 with their output interleaved. Once you remove catch from p2 you make the p2's microtask chain shorter, so the order of the output is changed.
You can think about the exact order in the both cases as an exercise, but the main is you have 2 chains of promises (microtasks) executing in parallel.
Once you grasp what a microtask is, the code will be easier to understand. And don't forget you can create a microtask yourself with queueMicrotask.
How promise callbacks are handled as microtasks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#task_queues_vs._microtasks
About microtasks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide/In_depth#tasks_vs_microtasks

Thank you for sharing your knowledge, but I already knew that knowledge. That's why I find it confusing to understand. If you have time, please run these examples and see if the results are the same as what you think. Many thanks!
